# Sending 405 from express.js when there is a route match but no HTTP method match

Tags: express

I'm looking for a clean way to have my express app return 405 Method Not Allowed if a client sends a request that matches a mapped url route but does not match the mapped HTTP method.

My current implementation is to have a default "catch-all" handler that tries to match the url against the register routes, ignoring the HTTP method. If there is a match, then we know to return a 405, otherwise we let express do its default 404 behavior.

I'm hoping there is a better way that doesn't involve running all the route matching twice (once by express, once by my handler).

Answer (score 24):

Here is an approach that I have used successfully with multiple Django applications and now with Node and Express. It is also follows [RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-66) that says the following about HTTP 405:

> The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid
> methods for the requested resource.

So, the key point is to **route the requests to the same handler** without regard to methods.

```
app.all('/page/:id', page.page);
app.all('/page/:id/comments', page.comments);
app.all('/page/:id/attachments', page.attachments);
...
```

The next point is to **validate the method in the handler** function 'comments'. Note that the handler is responsible for handling all the methods. In Django's world this is the only way to go because the framework forces you to separate the routing of the URLs from the actual action about to be performed against the resource the URL represents.

In the handler you **could** check the method like this...

```
exports.comments = function (req, res) {
    if (req.route.method === 'get') {
        res.send(200, 'Hello universe.');
    } else {
        res.set('Allow', 'GET');
        res.send(405, 'Method Not Allowed');
    }
}
```

...but as you can expect the code will quickly become **repetitious and not nice to read** especially when you have many handler functions and many different sets of allowed methods.

Therefore I prepared a **shortcut function** named *restful* for the job. Define the function wherever you want. I personally would place it in helpers.js under the same directory where the handler functions are implemented.

```
var restful = function (req, res, handlers) {
    // 
    // This shortcut function responses with HTTP 405
    // to the requests having a method that does not
    // have corresponding request handler. For example
    // if a resource allows only GET and POST requests
    // then PUT, DELETE, etc requests will be responsed
    // with the 405. HTTP 405 is required to have Allow
    // header set to a list of allowed methods so in
    // this case the response has "Allow: GET, POST" in
    // its headers [1].
    // 
    // Example usage
    //     
    //     A handler that allows only GET requests and returns
    //     
    //     exports.myrestfulhandler = function (req, res) {
    //         restful(req, res, {
    //             get: function (req, res) {
    //                 res.send(200, 'Hello restful world.');
    //             }
    //         });
    //     }
    // 
    // References
    //     
    //     [1] RFC-2616, 10.4.6 405 Method Not Allowed
    //     https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-66
    //     
    //     [2] Express.js request method
    //     http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.route
    //
    var method = req.route.method; // [2]
    if (!(method in handlers)) {
        res.set('Allow', Object.keys(handlers).join(', ').toUpperCase());
        res.send(405);
    } else {
        handlers[method](req, res);
    }
}
```

With *restful* it is now quite painless to handle 405 responses automatically and having proper Allow header being set. Just give a function for each method you allow and *restful* does the rest.

So lets modify the previous example:

```
exports.comments = function (req, res) {
    restful(req, res, {
        get: function (req, res) {
            res.send(200, 'Hello restful universe.');
        }
    });
}
```

Why the name *restful*? In [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) web it is quite essential for the API to obey the conventions like responsing with HTTP 405 to the request having non-supported method. Many of those conventions could be integrated to *restful* when needed. Therefore the name is *restful* and not something like *auto405* or *http405handler*.

Hope this helps. Any thoughts?

Comment: Seems like a great candidate for baking into the framework itself.

Comment: To get it to work in Express 4, I had to change `var method = req.route.method;` to `var method = (req.method || '').toLowerCase();`

Comment: Express deprecated res.send(status, body): Use res.status(status).send(body) instead

Comment: But why not safety-netting with `.all()`?

Comment: And the `Allow` header should also have `HEAD`, as [“The `app.get()` function is automatically called for the HTTP `HEAD` method in addition to the `GET` method if `app.head()` was not called for the path before `app.get()`.”](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#routing-methods)

Answer (score 18):

## Method 1: Use `.route()` and `.all()`

```
// Your route handlers
const handlers = require(`./handlers.js`);

// The 405 handler
const methodNotAllowed = (req, res, next) => res.status(405).send();

router
.route(`/products`)
.get(handlers.getProduct)
.put(handlers.addProduct)
.all(methodNotAllowed);
```

This works because requests are passed to the handlers in the order they are attached to the route (the request "waterfall"). The `.get()` and `.put()` handlers will catch GET and PUT requests, and the rest will fall through to the `.all()` handler.

## Method 2: Middleware

Create middleware which checks for allowed methods, and returns a 405 error if the method is not whitelisted. This approach is nice because it allows you to see and set the allowed methods for each route along with the route itself.

Here's the `methods.js` middleware:

```
const methods = (methods = ['GET']) => (req, res, next) => {
  if (methods.includes(req.method)) return next();
  res.error(405, `The ${req.method} method for the "${req.originalUrl}" route is not supported.`);
};

module.exports = methods;
```

You would then use the `methods` middleware in your routes like this:

```
const handlers = require(`./handlers.js`); // route handlers
const methods = require(`./methods.js`);   // methods middleware

// allows only GET or PUT requests
router.all(`/products`, methods([`GET`, `PUT`]), handlers.products);

// defaults to allowing GET requests only
router.all(`/products`, methods(), handlers.products);
```

Comment: None of these examples are actually valid because a response with 405 status MUST have a header "Accept" with the allowed methods.

Comment: You really should NOT return next(). Just call next(), the return is implied. If you do this, you may see weird promise errors later on

Answer (score 2):

Due to ambiguity, there really is no other way. Personally, I would do something like this:

```
var route = '/page/:id/comments'
app.get(route, getComments)
app.all(route, send405)

function send405(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error()
  err.status = 405
  next(err)
}
```

Either way, you have to check the routes twice.

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestion makes sense and is better than what I was currently doing.

Comment: This solution is not the way to go. [RFC 2616 (HTTP/1.1)](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-66) says about HTTP 405: "The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource." The solution cannot provide that list and therefore should not be considered valid. Check my answer for more suitable approach.

Answer (score 1):

Kinda old question but here is what i did. I just put this after all my routes but before my 400 handler

```
// Handle 405 errors
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var flag = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < req.route.stack.length; i++) {
    if (req.method == req.route.stack[i].method) {
      flag = true;
    }
  }
  if (!flag) {
    err = new Error('Method Not Allowed')
    err.status = 405;
    return next(err)
  }

  next();
});
```

Comment: I believe this only works on an older version of express. Now the route method is much different.

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing it this way:

Say if you have GET and POST method handlers for `/`. You can wrap the path with `app.route` or `router.route` and assign the handlers accordingly.

```
    app.route("/").get((req, res) => {
            /* DO SOMETHING*/
    }).post((req, res) => {
            /* DO SOMETHING*/
    }).all((req, res) => {
            res.status(405).send();
    });
```

- http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.route
- http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.route

A request will get matched to the route and filtered through the handlers. If a handler is present, it will get handled as usual. Else, it will reach the `all` handler that will set the status code to 405 and ending the request.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it like this :

```
/*paths here*/

router.get('/blah/path1', blah.do_something );
router.post('/blah/path2', blah.do_something_else );

/* if we get here we haven't already gone off down another path */

router.all('/*', (req,res) => { res.status(405), 
   res.json({'status':405,
             'message':req.method + ' not allowed on this route'}) 
});

/* simples */
```

Comment: An HTTP 405 response must have an `Allow` header. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.6

Comment: How do you differentiate between 404 and 405. That's fixing one problem but creating a bigger one as side effect.

Answer (score 0):

I thought this was a pretty interesting problem and so I dove deeeeeep down into the depths of the express app function and found a way to dynamically build a 405 error that includes all of the possible routes (without having to manually update anything when you add a new route).

```
app.use("", (req, _, next) => {
  const err = buildError(app, req);
  if (!err) return next();
  return next(err);
});
```

For those interested you can find the npm package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ez-405, and below is a quick example of what it looks like to use it.

```
const express = require("express");
const { buildError } = require("express-ez-405");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

const userRouter = require("./routes/user");
const mainRouter = require("./routes/main");
const nestedRouter = require("./routes/nested");

// // Routes
app.use("/main", mainRouter);
app.use("/user", userRouter);
app.use("/nested/route", nestedRouter);
// Routes

// 405 & 404 error catcher
app.use("", (req, _, next) => {
  const err = buildError(app, req);
  if (!err) return next();
  return next(err);
});
// 405 & 404 error catcher

// Error handling
app.use((err, _, res, __) =>
  res.status(err.status).json({ message: err.message })
);
// Error handling

const PORT = 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port: ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Once this in in there you never have to worry about updating it regardless of whether you add, remove, or change routing.