# Nodejs Express - return 405 for un-supported method

Tags: node.js, express

I'm running a standard NodeJs 8 with Express and currently when a request for an existing path but un-supported method comes in, Express return 404.

For example 'POST /login' is supported, but 'GET /login' is not, but it returns 404.

How can I make Express return 405 in such a case?

Here's the routes file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const loginController = require('../controllers/login');


router.route('/login').post(loginController.loginUser);

module.exports = router;
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply add the `.all()` handler to your route chain, like so:

```
const methodNotAllowed = (req, res, next) => res.status(405).send();

router
.route(`/login`)
.post(loginController.loginUser)
.all(methodNotAllowed);
```

## Explanation

This works because requests are passed to the handlers in the order they are attached to the route (the request "waterfall"). The `.post()` handler will catch your POST requests, and the rest will fall through to the `.all()` handler.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14882124/sending-405-from-express-js-when-there-is-a-route-match-but-no-http-method-match) for more details.

## Authenticating *all* POST routes

If you would like to ensure that the user is logged in for *all* POST requests, but return a 405 response for any other requests, you can use a regular expression to match all routes with `router.post('*')`, like so:

```
router
.post(`*`, loginController.loginUser)
.all(methodNotAllowed);
```

The problem with this approach, however, is that no 404 errors will ever be returned to the client, only 405. Therefore I recommend attaching the `methodNotAllowed` handler to each individual route, like in the first code snippet above. This approach will return 404 errors for routes that don't exist, but 405 errors for routes that do.

## Determining the available methods for a route

To determine which methods are allowed for a route, use `router.stack`:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {

  const methods = router.stack

  // Filter for the route that matches the currently matched route
  .filter(layer => layer.route.path === req.path)[0]
  .route
  .methods;

  if (!methods[req.method]) methodNotAllowed(req, res, next);
  else next();

});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, one more thing, is there an easy way to return which methods are allowed for this route? or just build such a response manually?

Comment: I've updated my answer with information on how to determine the allowed methods for a route.

Comment: Thanks again, but it seems to work for regular paths such as /login, but fails for paths which have a parameter, for example /getPermissions/:user_id.

It returns an error that 'Cannot read property path of undefined', for row '.filter(layer => layer.route.path === req.swagger.apiPath)[0]'

Comment: What if you have several routers that handle the same path but with different methods (Say, GET and POST each of two.)?

Comment: Additionally this is non-conforming per RFC, since a 405 response "must" be accompanied with an Allow header.

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this that way:**

```
app.route("/login")
  .get((req, res) => {
    /* HANDLE GET */
  })
  .post((req, res) => {
    /* HANDLE POST */
  })
  .all((req, res) => {
    res.status(405).send();
  });
```

**How it works?**

If request matches the route. It will go through the handlers. If a handler is present, it will be handled using that specific one. Otherwise, it will reach the 'all' handler that will set the status code to 405 and send the response.

**Here You can find the discussion about it:**
[405 issue](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/1895)

**@You question below:**

You can try that way:

***loginRoutes.js content:***

```
const router = require('express').Router();

router.route('/')
  .get((req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send()
  })

module.exports = router
```

***server file content:***

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const loginRoutes = require('./loginRoutes')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

router.use('/login', loginRoutes)
router.route('/login').all((req, res) => { res.status(405).send() })
app.use(router);

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`started on port: ${PORT}`))
```

Comment: Can I do something like this: app.use(loginRoutes).all((req, res) => {
    res.status(405).send();
  });
?

Comment: See edited message. You can check out nice project structure of routes/controllers here: https://github.com/linnovate/mean/tree/master/server

Comment: Yes, much more, thank you. One more thing, is there an easy way to return which methods are allowed for this route? or just build such a response manually?

Comment: First idea is to have a documentation hosted with Your API (for example swagger). You can also try to implement OPTIONS method on Your server. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS and here is the example how to handle that in express.js: http://johnzhang.io/options-request-in-express. For sure there are more ideas how to tackle that problem (maybe some API discover), You need to check it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet of code to automatically send 405 status code when route from the same path exist but not with the current method

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    const AllLayers = app._router.stack
    const Layers = AllLayers.filter(x => x.name === 'bound dispatch' && x.regexp.test(req.path))

    const Methods = [];
    Layers.forEach(layer => {
        for (let method in layer.route.methods) {
            if (layer.route.methods[method] === true) {
                Methods.push(method.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    })

    if (Layers.length !== 0 && !Methods.includes(req.method)) {

        res.setHeader('Allow', Methods.join(','))

        if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
            return res.send(Methods.join(', '))
        }
        else {
            return res.sendStatus(405);
        }
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Hope this could be helpfull to someone

Comment: the code above doesn't works with routers

Answer (score 0):

If you want to determine what methods COULD have been used you need to do a lot of digging in the `app` function you start your server with, and through some string manipulation and the like you can figure out what the possible methods are and return them in the error. If you're interested in how its done check out https://github.com/Justinlkirk/express-ez-405 or just use the npm package here https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ez-405